# Node.js, POST and DELETE requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, http, post

How can I set up **POST** and **DELETE** methods? 
I have:

```
const courses = [
  {path: bestCourse, name: 'course1'},
  {path: testCourse, name: 'course2'},
  {path: goodCourse, name: 'course3'},
];
 app.get('/api/courses', (req, res) => {
  res.send(courses);
});
```

I want to POST new course via {path} and get information about it with /api/courses/{path}:

```
app.get('/api/courses/{path}', (req, res) => {
  res.send(courses);
});
```

I have

```
app.post('/api/courses', (req, res) => {
  const course = {
    path: req.body.name,
    name: req.body.name
  };
  courses.push(course);
  res.send(course);
})
```

But I want to get information about new course with /api/courses/{path}.
Btw, what is the best way to DELETE this new course from /api/courses/{path}...

Thank you!

Comment: I think you need to narrow the scope of the question here - what exactly is it you are struggling with? You seem to be familiar with utilising HTTP verbs with Express so part is it you aren't sure about?

Comment: Here are the docs for express routing. Need some more details on what exactly you need help with, but it sounds like the "Route parameters" section might be what you are looking for? https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the array filter method of JS:

```js
app.get('/api/courses/:path', function (req, res) {
  res.send(courses.filter(course => course.path == req.params.path))
})
```